# Understanding Turbine/ Hystrix stream metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, turbine

I am working with our monitoring team in understanding the metrics output from the Turbine/ Hystrix stream. It will help them setup dashboards & they want to understand which bits they want to pic in their monitoring dashboards. They are using Kibana for configuring their dashboard.

I am struggling to find any documentation online which explains each element in the metrics. There is documentation for Hystrix configuration but nothing explaining the metrics which is output in JSON format when you request the stream.

```
{
    "data": {
        "rollingCountFallbackSuccess": 0,
        "rollingCountFallbackFailure": 0,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold": 40,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen": false,
        "propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds": 20000,
        "latencyTotal_mean": 215,
        "rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount": 0,
        "type": "HystrixCommand",
        "rollingCountResponsesFromCache": 0,
        "rollingCountBadRequests": 0,
        "rollingCountTimeout": 0,
        "propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy": "SEMAPHORE",
        "rollingCountFailure": 0,
        "rollingCountExceptionsThrown": 0,
        "rollingCountFallbackMissing": 0,
        "threadPool": "RibbonCommand",
        "latencyExecute_mean": 215,
        "isCircuitBreakerOpen": false,
        "errorCount": 0,
        "rollingCountSemaphoreRejected": 0,
        "group": "RibbonCommand",
        "latencyTotal": {
            "0": 203,
            "25": 203,
            "50": 203,
            "75": 227,
            "90": 227,
            "95": 227,
            "99": 227,
            "100": 227,
            "99.5": 227
        },
        "requestCount": 0,
        "rollingCountCollapsedRequests": 0,
        "rollingCountShortCircuited": 0,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds": 10000,
        "latencyExecute": {
            "0": 203,
            "25": 203,
            "50": 203,
            "75": 227,
            "90": 227,
            "95": 227,
            "99": 227,
            "100": 227,
            "99.5": 227
        },
        "rollingCountEmit": 0,
        "currentConcurrentExecutionCount": 0,
        "propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests": 200,
        "errorPercentage": 0,
        "rollingCountThreadPoolRejected": 0,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled": true,
        "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout": true,
        "propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled": true,
        "rollingCountFallbackRejection": 0,
        "propertyValue_requestLogEnabled": true,
        "rollingCountFallbackEmit": 0,
        "rollingCountSuccess": 0,
        "propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests": 20,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage": 100,
        "propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed": false,
        "name": "discovery-client",
        "reportingHosts": 2,
        "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride": "null",
        "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds": 120000,
        "propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds": 120000
    }
}
```

It will be great, even if I get any link to the documentation explaining above or any direction so that I can understand this better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring#command-metrics and https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#CommandMetrics ? I think they give a pretty summary of what these metrics mean and how to tweak them.